# python 上でsqlite の alter table文でカラム名を変数定義できない

Tags: python, sqlite

python 上でsqlite の alter table文のカラム名を変数定義できません。

select文・update文・insert文・delete文は、出来たのですがalter文だけエラーが出ます。

例えば、delete文だと当然以下で動作しました。

```
sql_del = 'DELETE FROM 作業員のタイムスタンプ WHERE NOT (担当者 like ? or 担当者 like ?)'
worker = ('作業員1%','下回り専属%',)
cur.execute(sql_del,worker)
```

select文等でも同様に「？」を使って検索条件の変数定義できました。

alter文だと以下で`OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`のエラーが発生します。

```
sql_alt = 'alter table 各号機の時系列 add column ? CHAR(30)'
new_col = ('new_col',)
cur2.execute(sql_alt,new_col)
```

ひょっとしてalter文だけ「？」を使って変数定義できないのでしょうか？
ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

基本的に，DataBase上で定義された文字は ? で置き換えられないと考えたほうがいいかもしれません．
例えば，テーブル名やカラム名などはデータベース上で定義された文字なので，? を使って変数を挿入できません．? が使えるのはあくまでパラメータのみでしょう．
こういう時はpython文字列 %s を使えば解決できます．
質問者様のクエリーを例に書き直してみます．

```
cur2.execute("alter table 各号機の時系列 add column %s char(50)" % new_col)
```

ただ，セキュリティを考えると，クエリーに文字列を使うこと自体があまりよくないみたいなので，多用するのは控えたほうがいいかもしれませんね．
一応，レファレンスも載っけておきます．
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/sqlite3.html#